# What does "that" indicate here? "data" or "range"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> A less obvious drawback is the limited range of data **that** the experiment can generate.

I wonder what does "that" indicate here?

1. range
2. data

I think "that" is an objective case of the relative clause here and it's the object of the verb "generate". So the answer would be 2 (data) but I want to be sure once again.

Comment: I would say: "the limited range of data".

Comment: A fuller context would be *"Nonetheless, experimenting on oneself remains deeply problematic. One obvious drawback is the danger involved; knowing that it existed does nothing to reduce it. A less obvious drawback is **the limited range of data** that the experiment can generate."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A less obvious drawback is the limited range of data that the experiment can generate.

It is ambiguous and could be either.

(a) *the limited range of (***data**-that-the-experiment-can-generate**)

or

(b) *the limited (***range**-of-data*) that the experiment can generate*

Comment: Yes, but the context seems to give a clue. The drawback is not the data itself, but the limits of it.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko  - I don't think that is enough to disambiguate. If the experiment is only capable of generating a limited range of data, then the data is the problem.  Maybe (b) is more likely though.

Answer (score 0):

A less obvious drawback is the limited range of data that the experiment can generate.

The limited **range** of data that the experiment can generate [which has a limited range of data that the experiment can generate] [which has a limited range of data that the experiment can generate] [which has a limited range of data that the experiment can generate][which has a limited range of data that the experiment can generate]

...

Limit

n-> ∞

Grammatically correct: this is grammar

[the limited range: Noun phrase]=**A** **OF** **B**=[Noun phrase: data that the experiment can generate]

A OF B (A is a subject? or B is a subject?: the concept of premodifier and postmodifier

If A is a subject, "OF B" is a prepositional phrase(postmodifier)

IF B is a subject, "A OF" is a premodifier

NOW: range of data -- which one is a subject? I go "range" (case of postmodifier)

X is range **[**OF B(=data that the experiment can generate)**]**

X is the limited range

X is the limited range (where X = A less obvious drawback)

A less obvious drawback is the limited range.

Conclusion: the antecedent of that is "data"